# Python class has no attribute '__new__' on one machine but not on another

Tags: python

I'm seeing some strange behavior in Python 3.8.10 on different machines.

I have a class with a copy method:

```
class Object():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def copy(self):
        cls = self.__class__
        result = cls.__new__(cls)  # Interesting enough this line causes an error on one machine but not on another, both running python 3.8.10
        ...
        return result
```

Nothing out of the ordinary. When I run the copy method of the class on my laptop, I get the error "AttributeError: class GO_relation has no attribute '**new**' ".
If I run however the same code on my desktop pc, I have no error and everything works fine. I am running the code with the pytest module and I found that on my desktop pc, the module is installed in a virtual environment and everything works fine. On my laptop however the pytest was installed with linux's apt on the system instead of in the virtual environment and somehow this end's up with this error.

I'd like to know what is happening? What am I missing exactly?

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.python.org/issue28672
Maybe that is a bug at python3.8